# Python Convert base64 to png

Tags: python

```
def signature_image(self,post):
        x = post.signature.split(",")
        with open("imageToSave.png", "wb") as fh:
            fh.write(base64.b64decode(x[1]))
```

When I try opening the png file it shows:
Fatal error reading PNG image file: Not a PNG file

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about field `signature` inside the `post` argument. Here is an example of saving an image from base64 encoded string:

```
import base64

def save_image(string):
    decoded = base64.decodebytes(string.encode("ascii"))
    with open("imageToSave.png", "wb") as fh:
        fh.write(decoded)
```

Comment: Provided a well-formed input, in which case does this work where the code in the question does not?